# stop double extension uplaod

Tags: php, regex, file-upload

hey i'm trying to verify if the user trying to upload a double extension file so for that i'm using the following code

```
function ExtensionValide($sFileName) {

        $fileNameInfo = array();
        if (preg_match('/.php.|.js./',$sFileName)) {
            return false;   # Tentative de masquer des extensions dangereuses !
        }
        else {
            $extension_valide = array('gif','png','jpg','jpeg','txt','pdf','html','mp3','csv');
            $extension_upload = strtolower(substr(strrchr($sFileName,'.'),1));
            $fileNameInfo[0] = in_array($extension_upload,$extension_valide);
            $fileNameInfo[1] = ".$extension_upload";
            $fileNameInfo[2] = basename($sFileName,$fileNameInfo[1]);
            return $fileNameInfo;
        }
    }
```

but the problem still that the user can uplaod .PHP.png with a capital letter so i'm trying to find if there is any regular expression that can handle the thnig in `preg_match('/.php.|.js./',$sFileName)` i want to say `preg_match('/.any_string./',$sFileName)` how can i do that

Comment: maybe you can use http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtolower.php strtolower before check? to convert all letters to lowercase?

Comment: @Danielius thank you very much you made it right

Comment: No problem, good luck :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you modify the regex to `preg_match('/.php.|.js.|.PHP.|.JS./')`, files with uppercase PHP or JS get matched. If you want to match all character, like you mentionen in `preg_match('/.any_string./',$sFileName)`, the regex is `preg_match('/`.[a-zA-Z]*.`/', $sFileName)`.
If you want to check, if there are more then one period character in the string, simply use the following code snippet as condition:

```
$condition = substr_count($sFileName, '.') > 1
```

Hope that it helps :)

Answer (score 2):

I am guessing that you are trying to stop file upload vulnerability over here. Stopping double `extension upload` is often abused by upload php files and executing them. The proper way to stop this type of attack would be to set proper permissions on your upload directory. Add read and write permission but not execute permission.

This will be simpler if you used amazon s3 or something.

Specifically to your use case,here is a sample code that you can use

```
<?php
$file_name = ''; //Unsecure file with double extention
$file_explode = explode(".",$file_name);
$extention = $file_explode[sizeof($file_explode)]; // Last extention
$file_new_name = uniqid()+"."+$extention;

//Save the file using $file_new_name
//Add database entry that maps $file_name to $file_new_name
?>
```

This way you can prevent double extension upload but again settings proper directory permissions is better that this method.